# Difference between com.thoughtworks.selenium and org.seleniumhq.selenium

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I have got a code with following imports:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.WebDriverBackedSelenium;
```

I tried to use `Maven` to resolve, but I can't found these packages on https://mvnrepository.com. There are packages only under `org.seleniumhq.selenium`, but these aren't able to resolve method calls in code and there aren't any `selenium` named packages under `com.thoughtworks`.

Comment: The group  id's don't need to match the packages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like those packages come from Selenium RC, from the times when it was created by ThoughtWorks.

See deprecated package list [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/deprecated-list.html), and migration guide [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_migrating_from_rc_to_webdriver.jsp#migrating-to-webdriver-reference).

You probably want to migrate by disposing of the old dependency, re-writing the client code according to documentation, and use WebDriver.

In that case, your Maven groupID would be `org.seleniumhq.selenium`, as documented [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations).

Comment: Upvote for the link to the deprecations list and the link to the migration guide.

Comment: Do we have any update on this? We are facing the same issue. We are using firefox extension of katalon automation recorder and this is generating the client code. When we export, we see this packages still in use. Any thoughts on how to deal with this @Mena. Because re-writing the client code using automation software doesnt make any sense as per the documentation. Katalon should take care of this...