# Upgrading selenium 2.x.x to 4.0.0 in maven project and fixing errors

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver

I am struggling to fix the errors after upgrading selenium from version 2x to 4 in the maven project.
Can someone please suggest to me steps and  how to resolve below error:

> error:package com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven does not exist

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would be helpful, you should follow the migration guide

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283866/difference-between-com-thoughtworks-selenium-and-org-seleniumhq-selenium)

Comment: thanks,will try this solution